# C# process.StandardOutput.ReadLine() return null

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a console application and try to use it in C# Asp.Net Core 3.1 WebApi application. The code I am using is as follow:

1. Create process

   ```
   Process process;
   process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   process.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
   process.Start();
   ```
2. Then I keep using the following code to send command to the console application and read the output

   ```
   process.StandardInput.WriteLine(argument);
   string output = string.Empty;
   do
   {
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
   } while (output == null);
   ```

The result is, for the first a few commands, I can get the result from ReadLine function correctly. However, after a few commands, I keep getting null and the whole application stuck at the while loop.

I ran the console application in console and send commands one by one that feed into the second step and all of them can return correct result and print the results in the console as expected.

Can anyone help what could be wrong? Thank you

Comment: Try to read the output asynchronously, subscribe to [`OutputDataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netcore-3.1) event and call [`BeginOutputReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline?view=netcore-3.1) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just created the solution with your aproach and everything is working correctly. I would advise you to use rather await `Task.Delay(50)` than `Thread.Sleep(50)` So having two such console application. Firstly the application i will want to call (i am calling it "External" one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string key = String.Empty;
    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"{key} was pressed in external program");
    } while (key != "q");
}
```

and the application that is calling this method:

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"[path_to_the_previous_console_app]\TestConsoleAppExternal.exe";
                process.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Write some key");
                string key = String.Empty;
                do
                {
                    key = Console.ReadLine();
                    await Interact(process, key);
                } while (key != "q");
            }
        }

        static async Task Interact(Process process, string argument)
        {
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(argument);
            string output = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                await Task.Delay(50);
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            } while (output == null);
            Console.WriteLine($"{argument} was pressed from Main process and readed output was: '{output}' ");
        }
```

And everything works as designed. What scenario exactly you want to achieve? What kind of application are you calling? Maybe this is the difference?

Comment: Thanks Piotr, your approach can improve a bit but did not completely solve the problem. I think the problem might be in the console application itself.

Comment: Yes, i thought this could be the issue;)

Answer (score 0):

`process.StandardOutput` returns a `StreamReader` instance; `StreamReader.ReadLine()` returns null if the end of the stream is reached (in our case this can mean that the process has terminated, or it has closed the standard output).